# Cloning private SSH Github repo from Cargo with Docker fails

Tags: docker, rust, ssh, rust-cargo

I am a bit lost with Docker, Cargo and SSH. I have this example project https://github.com/Jasperav/ssh-dockerfile. It is a hello world application with a docker file and a private dependency in the toml file. You can replace the dependency with your private dependency and just do `docker build -t something .`.

**I want to create a docker image of my application with a private repository**. I can not get it working, even not with the new `Buildkit` feature (`--mount=type=ssh`). I tried adding and removing stuff from the `Dockerfile`. I keep getting errors.

This is the content of my `Dockerfile` which is a combined effort of stuff I found on the internet:

```
FROM rust:1.65 AS builder

ENV CARGO_NET_GIT_FETCH_WITH_CLI=true

WORKDIR app
COPY . .
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh
RUN ssh-keyscan github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts

RUN --mount=type=ssh cargo build --release

FROM debian:buster-slim
COPY --from=builder ./target/release/docker ./target/release/docker

CMD ["./release/server"]
```

The error I get is:

```
 > [builder 6/6] RUN --mount=type=ssh cargo build --release:
#12 0.400     Updating git repository `ssh://git@github.com/xxx.git`
#12 1.171 error: failed to get `x` as a dependency of package `hello v0.1.0 (/app)`
#12 1.171 
#12 1.171 Caused by:
#12 1.171   failed to load source for dependency `x`
#12 1.171 
#12 1.171 Caused by:
#12 1.171   Unable to update ssh://git@github.com/xx.git
#12 1.171 
#12 1.171 Caused by:
#12 1.171   failed to clone into: /usr/local/cargo/git/db/xx
#12 1.171 
#12 1.171 Caused by:
#12 1.171   process didn't exit successfully: `git fetch --force --update-head-ok 'ssh://git@github.com/xx.git' '+HEAD:refs/remotes/origin/HEAD'` (exit status: 128)
#12 1.171   --- stderr
#12 1.171   Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address '140.82.121.4' to the list of known hosts.
#12 1.171   git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
#12 1.171   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
#12 1.171 
#12 1.171   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
#12 1.171   and the repository exists.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c cargo build --release]: exit code: 101
```

I am hoping that the SSH works from the host, but if I need to pass something in as build argument, it is also fine. The thing that did work is by having the access keys inside my dependency inside the Cargo.toml file, but that is really leaking too much info (and github will revoke the access key everytime I commit).

I can run the application fine without Docker. `git clone` also just works.

Comment: `I keep getting errors.` what errors? have you set up ssh access from your host to your private repo already?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I added the error message. I can git clone the private dependency from my host machine without any trouble. Cargo also works fine from the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was missing the `--ssh default` argument. It worked when I did build docker like this:

`docker build -t name --ssh default .`